# I couldn't find the homestead.yaml file

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Laravel in my windows. Now I want to edit homestead.yaml file but I couldn't find that file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because simply this is not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

run `homestead edit` and it will open the file for you